# Check and make list of jpg files if present to a text file using batch script

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt

I have a project which has following steps:

1. Create list of jpg files in a folder (initially there is none).
2. Go to step 1 if the created text file is empty.
3. Start another program (this program needs the received jpg file as input) if the created list file in step 1 is not empty.

JPG file will be sent to this folder by another process.

I am new to using batch script and used the following code from input.
But this program is not starting another process as required in step 3 even after receiving JPG file.

What is wrong with my code?

```
@echo off

set "dir=E:\test"
set "file=%dir%\a.txt"

:start

dir/b *.jpg>a.txt

if "%~z1" == "" (
    goto start
)
if "%~z1" == "0" (
    goto start
)
if "%~z1" == "1" (
    Start "" "C:\Users\vamsidhar muthireddy\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\database_test0\Debug\database_test0.exe"
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Don't name a variable like an internal command. It is possible to name a variable `dir` although there is also the command **DIR**, but it is not advisable.
2. Don't name a label like an internal command. It is possible to name a label `start` although there is also the command **START**, but it is not advisable.

Why is it not advisable to name a variable or label like a command?

Well, for example if in future somebody wants to find where variable `dir`  is used and the batch file contains also command **DIR**, or wants to rename label `start` by running a replace and batch file contains also command **START**, these actions become difficult as it must be analyzed in which context `dir` and `start` are used on each found occurrence.

Also syntax highlighting of batch file code is definitely not correct with commands **DIR** and **START** as the variable `dir` and the label `start` would be most likely also highlighted as commands.

The main coding mistake is `%~z1` as this is replaced by file size of the file specified with its file name as first argument on calling the batch file if the batch file was called at all with a file name of an existing file. But this is not the case here. The intention here was getting size of the list file. Also `if "%~z1" == "1"` will be nearly never true. This condition becomes only true if the file specified as parameter has a file size of exactly 1 byte.

Here is a commented batch code which I think is more useful for the task:

```
@echo off
set "SourceDirectory=E:\test"

rem This loop is executed with a delay of 5 seconds between each loop run
rem until at least 1 file with extension JPG is found in the defined source
rem directory. Then the JPG file is processed and batch processing ends.

:Loop
echo Checking for a *.jpg file in %SourceDirectory% ...
if exist "%SourceDirectory%\*.jpg" goto ProcessFile
%SystemRoot%\System32\ping.exe 127.0.0.1 -n 6 >nul
goto Loop

:ProcessFile
for %%I in ("%SourceDirectory%\*.jpg") do (
    echo Processing %%I ...
    start "" "%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\database_test0\Debug\database_test0.exe" "%%I"
)

rem Delete the created variable before exiting batch processing.
set "SourceDirectory="
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `ping /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `start /?`